# Is there any way to match Vth of 2 mosfets with different aspect ratio?

Tags: mosfet, analog, current-mirror, matching

For the floating mirror circuit to work properly, the threshold voltage of M1 and M2 must be the same. However, (W/L)1 ≠ (W/L)2. So I thought to get a first order matching I can match L1 and L2 (to match λ to get better mirroring accuracy) and to connect bulk to source (to remove the body effect). Is this the best I can achieve in matching or is there any other way to improve matching in Vth (and mirroring in general).

[image]

Comment: You can't tie the body of M2 to its source unless you have a P-well or twin well technology. If you put your NMOS on a p substrate then the substrate will likely be tied to ground.

Answer (score 1):

Look carefully, M1 and M2 are simply made up of different number of the SAME transistor, i.e (W/L)N. M1 contains 1 unit and M2 contains K units. This is how you achieve the best matching.

Trying to match Vth of different sized transistors is a hopeless venture even on the same chip! Heck, Vth matching of same sized transistors in different locations is hard enough and can be very layout dependent. Different sized devices will always give relatively large systematic mismatch error.

The best way to improve matching is by using area. Mismatch error for MOSFET's has been famously shown to be:

1) proportional to thickness of oxide - So thin oxide devices achieve best matching!

2) Inversely proportional to sqrt(WL) - Large area means good matching

Comment: It would also be wise to use exactly the same geometry and orientation for the features of M1 and M2...have the gate poly running the same way, always put the source on the left, etc.